# Link to Global Fields like you can with the entries fieldtype

Tags: fieldtypes, globals

Is there any way to link to a global using a field in a entry form, much like you would use the "Entries" fieldtype to link to entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly. You could have a dropdown of all the global set handles (use [Dynamic Fields Plugin](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-dynamicfields/) if you don't want to maintain this dropdown manually), and then in your template fetch the global set from its handle with [getSetByHandle](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.globals#getSetByHandle):

```
{% set globalSet = craft.globals.getSetByHandle(entry.globalSetHandle.value) %}
{% if globalSet %} {# could conceivably be null #}
  ... {{ globalSet.someField }} ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: ZOMG, that is absolutely beautiful. Thanks Marion!!